# Rotate3d() from top of div

Tags: html, css, 3d

I want a div to fold down from the top in webkit. I'm currently using rotate3D but this rotation is measured from the centre of the div. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform-origin`:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top center;
-moz-transform-origin: top center;
-o-transform-origin: top center;
-ms-transform-origin: top center;
transform-origin: top center;
```